# Use AWS Amplify DataStore without GraphQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

Is it possible to use AWS Amplify DataStore without GraphQL? I tried looking at the documentation and it has operations like save, query, etc only in GraphQL.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/datastore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently but GraphQL is just the implementation medium as it gives advantages around the transport as well as type inference for performing conflict resolution and sync. Without it you would need a proprietary way at the network layer to convey the same information. Is there a reason or use case you're looking to not use GraphQL?

Comment: I was more familar with using REST

Comment: @richard I'm interested in learning more about this.  I'm making a system that is a bit like airtable.  Its allows users to define their own data models through a UI.  So there is no modelgen step for me.  I would like to create the GraphQL schema programatically.  Is that possible?  Any docs that I should read?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `DataStore` looked like in January, but [the current documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js#persistence-operations) don't show any graphql to query/save objects.